# TryParse method is reading negative value and turning it to a positive 0 in VB.Net code

Tags: vb.net, sum, double, negative-number, tryparse

I created this code in order to get the total sum of these values.

```
  Dim budget As Double
  If gv_DO_Tasks.Rows.Count() = 0 Then
        lblTotalTaskTotalBudget.Text = ""
        Return
    End If
    For Each i As GridViewRow In gv_DO_Tasks.Rows
        Dim amount As String = Replace(i.Cells(6).Text, "$", " ")
        Dim value As Double
        If Double.TryParse(amount, value) = True Then               
            budget = budget + value
        End If
        
    Next
```

The issue is that I have a negative value as one of the amounts and when I try to do the TryParse method to convert the amount which is a string to a double, the value becomes 0 as a positive integer instead of the previous value which is ($26,652.25) or -$26,652.25 That messes up the total which is supposed to be less. The total sum is showing $989,992.74  but it should be $963,340.49.

Is there anything I have to add to the code or change?

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect replacing the dollar sign with a space is leaving you with something like this:

```
- 26,642.25
```

Notice the space between the negative sign and the value. If you replace the dollar sign with an empty string instead, I'd bet the code will work:

```
Dim amount As String = Replace(i.Cells(6).Text, "$", "")
```

I might also be tempted to write a utility/library method like this:

```
<Extension()> 
Public Shared Iterator Function WhereDoubleParses(Of T)(items As IEnumerable(Of T), selector As Func(Of T, Double)) As IEnumerable(Of Double)
    For Each item As T in items
         Dim result As Double
         If (Double.TryParse(selector(item), result) Then
              Yield result
         End If
    Next
End Function
```

Which I would then use to reduce the original `For` loop down to this:

```
budget = gv_DO_Tasks.Rows.
     WhereDoubleParses(Function(i) i.Cells(6).Text.Replace("$", "")).
     Sum()
```

Comment: I am now getting the error

Error: BC30456 'WhereDoubleParses' is not a member of 'GridViewRowCollection'.

Comment: This is now my code

```Dim budget As Double  
        budget = gv_DO_Tasks.Rows.
        WhereDoubleParses(Function(a) i.Cells(6).Text.Replace("$", "")).
     Sum() ```